# Packages for implementing a React-Native WebView

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I'm an an impasse after spending all day trying to implement a WebView. I've tried the 3 packages below as recommended by different threads throughout my search.

```
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview
https://github.com/teamairship/react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video
https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-webview-android
```

I've installed the packages and linked, but Android Studio either "cannot resolve symbol" or causes other build errors.

After gutting all references to these things, the app crashes "Native Component for RNCustomWebView Does Not Exist"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use custom packages. React native gives an in built [webview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview). Try to avoid external packages as much as possible.

Comment: The official docs direct to react-native-community/react-native-webview because webview is being/has been removed?

The instructions that package, as well as others, leave me in the same state with symbol issues in Android Studio.